# Get `id` field from output of Openstack creation commands in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, awk, openstack

OpenStack commands (e.g. `cinder create`, `nova boot`, `glance image-create`) output a table of details about the new volume/instance/image.

```
$ cinder create --image 3896b01c-6afb-41a4-a207-3db87527be2c --display-name centos7-cloud 30
+---------------------+--------------------------------------+
|       Property      |                Value                 |
+---------------------+--------------------------------------+
|     attachments     |                  []                  |
|  availability_zone  |                 nova                 |
|       bootable      |                false                 |
|      created_at     |      2017-01-12T10:58:00.782361      |
| display_description |                 None                 |
|     display_name    |            centos7-cloud             |
|      encrypted      |                False                 |
|          id         | d1c6369b-73ce-498e-a2ef-2c6cea1d0f90 |
|       image_id      | 3896b01c-6afb-41a4-a207-3db87527be2c |
|       metadata      |                  {}                  |
|         size        |                  30                  |
|     snapshot_id     |                 None                 |
|     source_volid    |                 None                 |
|        status       |               creating               |
|     volume_type     |                 None                 |
+---------------------+--------------------------------------+
```

I am creating a shell script where the next command refers to the new volume by `id` (in variable `CINDER_ID`).

```
nova boot --block-device source=volume,id=${CINDER_ID},dest=volume centos
```

What is the best way to extract the `id` to a variable?

Comment: Why was the OpenStack tag removed?  This is an key part of the OpenStack CLI and I would like to know if there is a standard way that it is solved.

Comment: You needed an answer in utilities in `shell`, in this case `bash`. So it didn't seem reasonable to have the others. Also the rationale is any help you will be getting for this will be using shell utilities, so it seemed best to retain those tags alone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following solution using `GNU grep` which supports look around.

```
grep -owP 'id.*\|\s\K.*[^\|]+' inputfile
d1c6369b-73ce-498e-a2ef-2c6cea1d0f90
```

To storing it to a variable:

```
id=$(grep -owP 'id.*\|\s\K.*[^\|]+' inputfile)
```

You can try:

```
 id=$(cinder create --image 3896b01c-6afb-41a4-a207-3db87527be2c --display-name centos7-cloud 30 |grep -owP 'id.*\|\s\K.*[^\|]+' )
```

Comment: Nice, the `-o`, `-w` and `\K` were all new to me.

Comment: For some reason, your command is producing empty output on `grep (GNU grep) 2.26`. Have the same file as the OP's table in a file

Comment: It is working for me with `grep (GNU grep) 2.20`.  Both from file and piped from the command.

Comment: mine is `sh-4.1$ grep --version
GNU grep 2.6.3`

Answer (score 2):

Using `GNU awk's`, [gensub-function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html), you can do something like below. The function in the below logic, removes the leading and trailing whitespaces from columns 2,3 field-separated by `|`

(checked with writing the table to a file)

```
awk -F"|" 'gensub(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/,"","g",$2)=="id"{print gensub(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/,"","g",$3);}' file
d1c6369b-73ce-498e-a2ef-2c6cea1d0f90
```

To store it in a variable,

```
idValue="$(awk -F"|" 'gensub(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/,"","g",$2)=="id"{print gensub(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/,"","g",$3);}' file)"
printf "%s\n" "$idValue"
d1c6369b-73ce-498e-a2ef-2c6cea1d0f90
```

You can pipe your command producing the above table to this `Awk` as

```
<your-command> | awk '{..}'
```

Something like,

```
cinder create --image 3896b01c-6afb-41a4-a207-3db87527be2c --display-name centos7-cloud 30 \
       | awk -F"|" 'gensub(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/,"","g",$2)=="id"{print gensub(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/,"","g",$3);}'
d1c6369b-73ce-498e-a2ef-2c6cea1d0f90
```

Comment: Thank you, but I prefer the more concise variants above.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\s*\|\s*` as field separator

```
CINDER_ID=$(cinder create --image 3896b01c-6afb-41a4-a207-3db87527be2c --display-name centos7-cloud 30 |
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\\s*\\|\\s*"}$2=="id"{print $3}')
echo $CINDER_ID
```

you get

```
d1c6369b-73ce-498e-a2ef-2c6cea1d0f90
```

Comment: Thanks, that is nice and concise.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative that I came up with is the following `sed`

```
sed -n 's/|\s*id\s*|\s*\(.*\S\)\s*|/\1/p' inputfile
d1c6369b-73ce-498e-a2ef-2c6cea1d0f90
```

Storing in a variable,

```
CINDER_ID=$(cinder create --image 3896b01c-6afb-41a4-a207-3db87527be2c \
--display-name centos7-cloud 30 | sed -n 's/|\s*id\s*|\s*\(.*[^\s]\)\s*|/\1/p' )

echo $CINDER_ID
d1c6369b-73ce-498e-a2ef-2c6cea1d0f90
```

Answer (score 2):

Given that the column values are surrounded by whitespace (in *addition to* the `|` column separators), **`awk`'s default field-splitting behavior will do** (the `|` instances then simply count as fields in their own right):

```
cinder_ID=$(cinder create ... | awk '$2=="id" {print $4}')
```

<sup>You could append `; exit` inside the block to stop processing right away; probably not worth it for such a small input set, however.</sup>

Note that I've changed your variable name from `CINDER_ID` to `cinder_ID`, because it is **better not to use all-uppercase shell-variable names** in order to [avoid conflicts with environment variables and special shell variables](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_01).

Answer (score 1):

I think you do not need any Fancy regular expression matchings here. After you create an image with some name , you can this issue this command to get the image id.

```
# openstack image list -f value | grep '<Image name>' | awk '{print $1}'
```

You can do the same for volume.

```
# openstack volume list -f value | grep '<volumename>' | awk '{print $1}'
```

Comment: This only works if the name is unique.  I cannot guarantee that.